# Linear interpolation among columns in r

Tags: r, interpolation

I am working with some temperature data where I have temperatures at certain depths e.g. 0.9m, 2.5m and 5m. I would like to interpolate this values so I obtain the temperature each meter, e.g. 1m, 2m and 3m. The original data looks like this:

```
df
# A tibble: 5 x 3
  date                d_0.9 d_2.5  
  <dttm>              <dbl> <dbl> 
1 2004-01-05 03:00:00  7     8        
2 2004-01-05 04:00:00  7.5   9      
3 2004-01-05 05:00:00  7     8        
4 2004-01-05 06:00:00  6.92  NA
```

What I would like to get is something like :

```
df_int
# A tibble: 5 x 5
  date                 d_0.9   d_1      d_2      d_2.5  
  <dttm>              <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
1 2004-01-05 03:00:00  7       7.0625   7.6875   8     
2 2004-01-05 04:00:00  7.5     7.59375  8.53125  9      
3 2004-01-05 05:00:00  7       7.0625   7.6875   8  
4 2004-01-05 06:00:00  6.92    NA       NA       NA
```

I have to do this for a very large data frame. Is there an efficient way of doing it?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to convert the data to long format, use a join to add rows for the depths we want to interpolate at, and then use `approx` for the interpolation:

```
library(tidyverse)

# Data
df = tibble(date=seq(as.POSIXct("2004-01-05 03:00:00"),
                     as.POSIXct("2004-01-05 06:00:00"),
                     by="1 hour"),
            d_0.9 = c(7,7.5,7,6.92),
            d_2.5 = c(8,NA,8,NA),
            d_5.0 = c(10,10.5,9.4,NA))

# Create a data frame with all of the times and depths we want to interpolate at
depths = sort(unique(c(c(0.9, 2.5, 5), seq(ceiling(0.9), floor(5), 1))))
depths = crossing(date=unique(df$date), depth = depths)

# Convert data to long format, join to add interpolation depths, then interpolate
df.interp = df %>% 
  gather(depth, value, -date) %>% 
  mutate(depth = as.numeric(gsub("d_", "", depth))) %>% 
  full_join(depths) %>% 
  arrange(date, depth) %>% 
  group_by(date) %>% 
  mutate(value.interp = if(length(na.omit(value)) > 1) {
    approx(depth, value, xout=depth)$y
  } else {
    value
  })
```

In the code above, the `if` statement is inclduded to prevent `approx` throwing an error when a given `date` has only one non-missing value.

```
df.interp
```

> ```
>                   date depth value value.interp
> 1  2004-01-05 03:00:00   0.9  7.00     7.000000
> 2  2004-01-05 03:00:00   1.0    NA     7.062500
> 3  2004-01-05 03:00:00   2.0    NA     7.687500
> 4  2004-01-05 03:00:00   2.5  8.00     8.000000
> 5  2004-01-05 03:00:00   3.0    NA     8.400000
> 6  2004-01-05 03:00:00   4.0    NA     9.200000
> 7  2004-01-05 03:00:00   5.0 10.00    10.000000
> 8  2004-01-05 04:00:00   0.9  7.50     7.500000
> 9  2004-01-05 04:00:00   1.0    NA     7.573171
> 10 2004-01-05 04:00:00   2.0    NA     8.304878
> 11 2004-01-05 04:00:00   2.5    NA     8.670732
> 12 2004-01-05 04:00:00   3.0    NA     9.036585
> 13 2004-01-05 04:00:00   4.0    NA     9.768293
> 14 2004-01-05 04:00:00   5.0 10.50    10.500000
> 15 2004-01-05 05:00:00   0.9  7.00     7.000000
> 16 2004-01-05 05:00:00   1.0    NA     7.062500
> 17 2004-01-05 05:00:00   2.0    NA     7.687500
> 18 2004-01-05 05:00:00   2.5  8.00     8.000000
> 19 2004-01-05 05:00:00   3.0    NA     8.280000
> 20 2004-01-05 05:00:00   4.0    NA     8.840000
> 21 2004-01-05 05:00:00   5.0  9.40     9.400000
> 22 2004-01-05 06:00:00   0.9  6.92     6.920000
> 23 2004-01-05 06:00:00   1.0    NA           NA
> 24 2004-01-05 06:00:00   2.0    NA           NA
> 25 2004-01-05 06:00:00   2.5    NA           NA
> 26 2004-01-05 06:00:00   3.0    NA           NA
> 27 2004-01-05 06:00:00   4.0    NA           NA
> 28 2004-01-05 06:00:00   5.0    NA           NA
> ```